# Move code to nested query to resolve copypaste

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have sql query

Here is code

```
 SELECT  tt.creationdate AS CreatedDate,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) AS DaysOpen,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 180 THEN '180+ Days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 150 THEN '150 - 180 Days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 120 THEN '120 - 150 Days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
             WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) >= 0 THEN '0 - 30 Days'
                ELSE NULL END AS TaskAging,
                tms.SupportType,
                tms.SupportModule,
                tt.*
FROM    public.tasks tt

LEFT JOIN       
        public.tasks_meta_support tms
ON      tms.taskid = tt.Id

WHERE   tt.issupportticket = 1
        AND tt.supportorganizationid = 65277
        AND tt.completeddate IS NULL
        AND tt.isdeleted = 0
```

I need to move `DaysOpen` to nested query to reuse it in CASE

How I can do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT tt.DaysOpen,
       (CASE WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 180 THEN '180+ Days'
             WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 150 THEN '150 - 180 Days'
             WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 120 THEN '120 - 150 Days'
             WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
             WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
             WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
             WHEN tt.DaysOpen >= 0 THEN '0 - 30 Days'
        END )AS TaskAging,
       tms.SupportType,
       tms.SupportModule,
       tt.*
FROM (SELECT tt.*, DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(tt.creationdate AS DATE), GETDATE()) AS DaysOpen
      FROM public.tasks tt
     ) tt LEFT JOIN       
     public.tasks_meta_support tms
     ON tms.taskid = tt.Id
WHERE   tt.issupportticket = 1
        AND tt.supportorganizationid = 65277
        AND tt.completeddate IS NULL
        AND tt.isdeleted = 0;
```

Note that the `ELSE` is redundant, so I removed it.

Comment: Thank's it helped

Answer (score 0):

First I would move the GETDATE() to @Now and set it just before the query. You might get a difference in behaviour if this run 23:59:59.999, but in general you want the values fromwhen you asked, not when it's running.
Also try not to use wildcards when selecting columns.

Also, do you want all rows from public.tasks and only the matching one from publi.tasks_meta_support or all rows from public.tasksmeta_support? The order you write thing is really important here ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms177634(v%3dsql.90)#e-using-the-sql-92-left-outer-join-syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms177634(v%3Dsql.90)#e-using-the-sql-92-left-outer-join-syntax)).

That said you could use a CTE or some a subquery.
I would go with a CTE and writing out all the columns.

Not knowing which columns there are in public.tasks maybe this subquery?
Note that I moved everything related to public.tasks to tt.

```
DECLARE @Now datetime;

SET @Now = @Now;


SELECT  ptsq.CreatedDate,
        ptsq.DaysOpen,
        ptsq.TaskAging,
        tms.SupportType,
        tms.SupportModule,
        ptsq.*
FROM    (SELECT creationdate AS CreatedDate,
                DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) AS DaysOpen,
                CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 180 THEN '180+ Days'
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 150 THEN '150 - 180 Days'
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 120 THEN '120 - 150 Days'
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(creationdate AS DATE), @Now) >= 0 THEN '0 - 30 Days'
        FROM public.tasks
        WHERE issupportticket = 1
              AND supportorganizationid = 65277
              AND isdeleted = 0) ptsq
LEFT OUTER JOIN public.tasks_meta_support tms ON ptsq.taskid = tms.Id -- Assuming you want all rows from public.tasks.
WHERE ptsq.completeddate IS NULL -- Could probably be moved to ptsq
```

Comment: DECLARE is great in sql server. But in Redshift it will not work

Comment: Sorry, missed that flag :)